# How do I figure out what is eating up ports in Azure MVC website?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET MVC website deployed as an Azure Website and every few days I keep getting errors like this:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An operation on a socket could not
>   be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or
>   because a queue was full

Once I start getting these errors the entire site goes down and it seems like all the outgoing ports have been exhausted. I have to change the capacity of the Azure website to get it to restart and clean out the ports so it will start working again.

How can I figure out what is eating up these ports? Is there tracing I can use for an Azure website? I don't have the ability to remote desktop into a machine since it is a hosted service. Some of the services that would be using outgoing ports are:

- Making SQL Server calls with Entity Framework
- Pulling down and caching assets from Azure Blob Storage with the Image Resizer plugin
- Sending email via SMTP through SendGrid

Comment: I would run Code Analysis on the project to find out if you don't correctly dispose of disposable objects.

Comment: @fejesjoco I use Entity Framework and don't always specifically call Dispose on the DataContext. What is the best way to do that?